# The "Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v11.1'" error occurs in a deployed application

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I am evaluating DevExpress and built a simple grid that works perfectly in Visual Studio but when I copy the site to my webserver I am unable to run my web site. I am getting a configuration error (listed below).

Configuration Error :

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

```
Line 19: <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
Line 20: <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
Line 21: <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
Line 22: <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
Line 23: <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
```

Comment: What do you want to convey here?

Comment: I am evaluating DevExpress and built a simple grid that works perfectly in visual studio but when I copy the site to my webserver I am unable to run my web site.I am getting a configuration error(listed below).
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' o

Comment: Source Error:

Line 19: <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
Line 20: <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
Line 21: <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
Line 22: <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />

Comment: do you have all the assemblies in your bin-Folder on your Server? also all required DevExpress.*.dll's? If no, try this first

Comment: how can all DevExpress.*.dll's?

Comment: When you publish your application then do not forget to set "Copy Local" flag for referenced DevExpress dll's. It will defiantly solve your issue if you are using same version of dlls as referenced in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Your Project is missing the DevExpress dll on the server (in this Case: DevExpress.Web.v11.1.dll)

To solve this problem: copy the DevExpress dll from your DevExpress install folder (by Default: c:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 11.1\Components\Bin\Framework) to your bin folder on the server. Maybe you have to add the assembly in your web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
        <assemblies>
            ....
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1 ..."/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

The reason why your project runs just fine in Visual Studio is your GAC (global assembly cache) where all DevExpress dll's are stored and available for you in Visual Studio.

A second solution (which **binds** you to a specific Version) is to install DevExpress v11.1 on your Server. Once you find an error in your Application solved by an update (from v11.1.3 to v11.1.4) you have to update ALL your applications on the Server.